# Hovering over 'Delete' on your own post prompts you to 'vote to delete'

Tags: bug, design, 10k-tools

When I hover over my own question's delete button it says *vote to delete* instead of just *delete*.

I am not at the required privilege level to able to *vote* to delete posts on this site - and when deleting my own posts, it should be instantaneous - they should not be put into a queue for deletion. I guess this is a bug?

[image: 'vote to delete' my own post]

Comment: Strange - seems like the tooltip may be reused from the delete button control for those who do have the reputation to delete other posts.  However, this may be intended.  I found a [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/why-do-i-have-to-vote-to-delete-my-own-answer) that I think relates to this as well.